# adding comment box in bottom page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

i make a page test.php with image slide jquery cycle effect, beatport player and other effect all is ok and run..

i try to add comment box on bottom with this code

```
<div id="fb-root">fb:comments href="https://www.facebook.com/pageadresse" num_posts="8" width="500"></fb:comments> </div>
```

and positionning comment box via Css

when i test http://myserver/iframe/test.php its ok comment box appears ..
but when i add application to my page comment box dissapears
any help??

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, make sure you have added an xml namespace to the HTML tag of your doc ->

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

**Second**, the code you provided is missing an opening '<' tag, so it should be ->

```
<fb:comments href="https://www.facebook.com/pageadresse" num_posts="8" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

**Third**, you don't need to put it in a `<div id="fb-root"></div>`, the fb-root div is only needed somewhere on the page for the facebook js-sdk to work.

You can include the javascript sdk and the comment plugin all in one like this ->

```
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<fb:comments href="https://www.facebook.com/pageadresse" num_posts="2" width="500">
</fb:comments>
```

More info here -> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/